# appcelerator titanium imageview thumbnail open full size with singletap

Tags: mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have a header bar with a thumbnail image, and I want to make it so a user can tap the image and have it pop-up to full size.

the banner was created with something like:

```
bannerView = Titanium.UI.createView
```

and the image added like

```
logo = Titanium.UI.createImageView
bannerView.add(logo)
```

(I didn't copy and paste the exact code this is just an example)

I have searched the Titanium documentation and there is probably something simple I'm not finding, but I'm wondering what is the easiest way to make this work?

I'm planning to use an event listener on the singletap event, but am not sure how best to display the image? as a modal? I don't think an alert allows you to add an image?

Ideally, the user can also click again to close the zoomed in view.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work. Add your header to main view say view1 i.e. the view with width : Ti.UI.FILL and then add header to view1.

Then on click on bannerView, add one more view say view2 with FILL width and add view2 to view1 and in that view2 add imageView with FILL height and width.

If you will provide some code then I can properly help you.